# How to Get Newly Created Lync 2013/Skype for Business Chat Room URL

Tags: c#, chat, lync-2013, skype-for-business

I have the following code, which I'm fairly sure *could* work, but I'm not sure what to assign "conferenceAccess" considering the chat is newly created. Does anyone have any idea how to go about this?

```
        if (_lyncAutomation != null)
        {
            AutomationModalities mode = AutomationModalities.InstantMessage;
            var convoSettings = new Dictionary<AutomationModalitySettings, object>();
            convoSettings.Add(AutomationModalitySettings.Subject, chatTitle);
            convoSettings.Add(AutomationModalitySettings.FirstInstantMessage, chat);
            convoSettings.Add(AutomationModalitySettings.SendFirstInstantMessageImmediately, true);

            try
            {
                _lyncAutomation.BeginStartConversation(mode, participants, convoSettings,
                                                  StartConversationCallback, null);

                ConferenceAccessInformation conferenceAccess = ConferenceAccessInformation;
                string chatURL = conferenceAccess.ExternalUrl;

            }
```

To be clear, the code above works perfectly, except for the last couple lines which I just added to do this.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Please verify the way in which the last couple of lines fail to work.  I suspect you get a compiler error as you are trying to construct a class without a public constructor.

Comment: Hi @PaulHodgson,

It's failing to compile because 

"ConferenceAccessInformation conferenceAccess = *ConferenceAccessInformation*;"

is saying "ConferenceAccessInformation "is a type which is not valid in this context".